# My divs wont go in the middle

Tags: html

Ok so here is my question i have a website and in the middle i have a section and a aside. every thing else on the page is 100% but the section and aside i want to equal 80% and me aligned next to each other in the middle. but instead i get this.

IMAGE: https://twitter.com/iamalecgrogan/status/392454057345810432/photo/1

before you start saying stuff i have tried every thing doing table-cell and table verticaly align and in-line block elemets creating a div for them to go into. but nothing is working please help. here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
Home | ProvideWebDesign
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header id="header">

<div id="header_right">
</div>

<div id="header_left">
</div>

</header>

<nav id="nav">
</nav>

<section id="section">

<article id="section_article">
</article>

<article id="section_article2">
</article>

</section>

<aside id="aside">

<article id="aside_article">
</article>

<article id="aside_article2">
</article>

<article id="aside_article3">
</article>

</aside>

<footer id="footer">

<div id="footer_right">
</div>

<div id="footer_left">
</div>

</footer>

</div>

</body>

 </html>

CSS--------------------

 *
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper
{
width: 100%;
height: 875px;
display: table;
}

#header
{
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
display: block;
}

#header_right
{
width: 50%;
height: 75px;
float: left;
display: block;
}

#header_left
{
width: 50%;
height: 75px;
float: left;
display: block;
}

#nav
{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
display: block;
}

#section
{
  width: 60%;
height: 600px;
float: left;
display: table-cell;
}
#aside
{
width: 20%;
height: 600px;
float: left;
display: table-cell;
 }

#footer
{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
display: block;
clear: both;
}

#footer_right
{
width: 50%;
height: 150px;
float: left;
display; block;
}

#footer_left
{
width: 50%;
height: 150px;
float: left;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the css styles. And please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: what?? i am new to stack over flow

Comment: Ok, we need the content of your layout.css and style.css.

Answer (score 1):

Create a containing element such as a div around the section and aside, give that container a width of 80%, block display, and margin auto. Lose the table-cell display on the section and aside. Give the container a clear fix: https://gist.github.com/jelmerdemaat/3804403

Comment: @Alec Robert Grogan I added a link.

Comment: is there any thing i need to change such as names in the cs.before and after like is there any names i change and thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: i pasted the code in from the link you gave me where do i put it i just pasted it is there a area where it needs to go?

Comment: If you're using the exact code from that gist, then give your new container class="cf" so the container will get the CSS styles of the clearfix. The clearfix code goes in your CSS style sheet.

Comment: i did every thing link you said it still didn't work tomorrow i will post all the code again please keep helping me